# How to match requests containing greater-than symbol (<) in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to harden a back end server, for which nginx is acting as a reverse proxy, against XSS and HTML injection attacks. I want to be able to simply respond with a 400 error to any request containing a '<' or a '>', either as part of the request or the query string (e.g., /LookupPrice?name=<"haarsy%0A>). I tried the following (for query_string) but the requests are still getting through:

```
if ($query_string ~* <){
      return 400;
}
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request URI is percent encoded, so `<>` are often encoded as %3C and %3E (although they are not listed as reserved characters in [RFC3986](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc3986.pdf)). Nginx will decode the characters to URI part when constructing the normalised URI variable `$uri`. But the query string remains percent encoded.

To match either `<` or `>` in the query string, whether percent encoded or not, use:

```
if ($query_string ~* (%3[CE]|[<>])) { return 400; }
```

Comment: Thanks, did the job perfectly!